# pnpm build dist has .pnpm.js how to solve it

Tags: vuejs3, vite, pnpm

In the vite + vue3 project, I use pnpm to install dependencies, and when I execute pnpm run build,It seems that the public package is packaged as as .pnpm.js
[please check this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v8Uvo.png)

when i use npm to install dependencies, it is normalize